Error LNK2019 unresolved external symbol - MASM (Assembly) + C++ problem with running the project
I need your help with running my code.
Here it is:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
extern "C"
{
    void asmMain(void);
    int asmScanf(char* dest, int maxLen);
}
int asmScanf(char* dest, int maxLen)
{
    char* result = fgets(dest, maxLen, stdin);
    if (result != NULL)
    {
        int len = strlen(result);
        if (len > 0)
        {
            dest[len - 1] = 0;
        }
        return len;
    }
    return NULL;
}
void clrscr(void)
{
    system("cls");
}
int main(void)
{
    clrscr();
    printf("Start asemblerskog programa: %s\n");
    asmMain();
    printf("Kraj asemblerskog programa.\n");
    return 0;
}

.const
option casemap:none
NULL            equ     0
noviRed         equ     10
maxDuzina       equ     256
.data
decBroj         db "Decimalni broj: ", 0
unosBroj        db "Uneseni broj u decimalnom obliku: %s", noviRed, 0
hexBroj         db noviRed, "Uneseni broj u heksadecimalnom obliku: %X", noviRed, 0
unos            db maxDuzina dup(?)
broj            dd 0
.code
externdef printf:proc
externdef asmScanf:proc
externdef atoi:proc
externdef exit:proc
public asmMain
asmMain proc
    push    rbp
    mov     rbp, rsp
    sub     rsp, 8    

    lea     rcx, decBroj
    xor     rdx, rdx   
    call    printf

    lea     rcx, unos     
    lea     rdx, [maxDuzina]  
    call    asmScanf

    lea     rcx, unos     
    mov     rdx, r8        
    call    printf

    lea     rcx, unos     
    call    atoi
    mov     dword ptr [broj], eax   

    mov     eax, dword ptr [broj]   
    lea     rcx, hexBroj
    call    printf

    add     rsp, 8     
    mov     rsp, rbp
    pop     rbp
    xor     eax, eax   
    call    exit       
asmMain endp
end

No matter which code I have (I even tried printing Hello World), I get these errors:
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State   
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol printf referenced in function asmMain        
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State   
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol asmScanf referenced in function asmMain

ANY SUGGESTIONS AND SOLUTIONS ARE MORE THAN WELCOME!
I put .masm in Customize dependencies, I've added main in Linker and put MASM in .asm file (Properties, Item Type).. I need the solution for my problem!

Visual Studio now defaults printf to being a function included with a compiled C source file, but you can use the legacy library to avoid this issue:
;       include C libraries
        includelib      msvcrtd
        includelib      oldnames
        includelib      legacy_stdio_definitions.lib    ;for scanf, printf, ...

        .data
msg     db      "test",00dh,00ah,000h
        .code
        extern  printf:near

main    proc
        sub     rsp,32                  ;caller allocates space for rcx,rdx,r8,r9
        lea     rcx,msg
        call    printf
        add     rsp,32
        xor     rax,rax
        ret
main    endp
        end

32 bit example:
        .686p                   ;enable instructions
        .xmm                    ;enable instructions
        .model flat,c           ;use C naming convention (stdcall is default)

;       include C libraries
        includelib      msvcrtd
        includelib      oldnames
        includelib      legacy_stdio_definitions.lib    ;for scanf, printf, ...

        .data                   ;initialized data
msg     db      "test",0dh,0ah,0
        .code                   ;code 
        extrn   printf:near
        public  main

main    proc
        push    offset msg
        call    printf
        add     esp,4 
        xor     eax,eax
        ret
main    endp
        end


I tried that in 32-bit mode but it still cannot find a definition for printf. Is this a 64 bit only solution?

@OldBoy - I added a 32 bit stdcall example to my answer.

Thank you guys for your help. Yes, I need certain libraries - precisely, these helped me:
includelib legacy_stdio_definitions.lib
includelib ucrt.lib
EXTERN printf: PROC
EXTERN scanf: PROC
EXTERN exit: PROC
